# Hide the up/down vote arrows on your own posts

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts)

Since users can't vote for their own questions, what's the point of having the voting arrows.  Sometimes I leave a number of tabs open, most often with questions I've asked so that I can check their progress for answers.  I've inadvertently tried to up/downvote my own questions a few times (ones that I had forgotten I had asked).

I propose that it might be less confusing to remove the up/down vote arrows on your own questions.
1. You will quickly see that this is your own post.
2. It will confuse newbies less.

Comment: It doesn't help with the "newbies" issue, but this sounds like a job for Greasemonkey.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, then we'll get questions about "why doesn't this post have voting arrows?!"

I believe it's better to show standard consistent UI, then tell the user why they can't do something, rather than hiding it.

Comment: I see your point, thanks for responding so quickly Jeff.

Comment: I have to disagree with this philosophy. Why not keep the arrows, but gray them out (or something) so they look disabled? You can still pop up a message if you try to click them explaining the situation.

Comment: If consistency is the goal, then why are voting arrows hidden for a user's own *comments*, but not for that user's own *questions and answers*?