# Hide voting arrows on deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface, deleted-posts

> **Related (but different):**
>
> - [Hide the up/down vote arrows on your own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52595/hide-the-up-down-vote-arrows-on-your-own-posts)

Currently deleted posts still display the downvote arrows:

[image: Y U NO LET ME VOTE]

But obviously trying to vote one way or the other is prevented:

[image: Y U SHOW ARROW THEN]

Can we just hide the voting arrows completely then?  This applies to both questions *and* answers since they are treated the same way in this respect (both show the arrows and neither allow voting).

Comment: Also, our own posts, posts that are locked, etc.

Comment: Not a big deal, but if the user has already voted, would they still be able to see which way they voted?

Comment: @BoltClock there's a separate request for each of those, but as far as I could tell, not one for deleted posts

Comment: @Brandon would it matter?  You could implement it such that if a vote were present just display that arrow, but that may be more confusing than it'd be worth

Comment: Who tries to vote on deleted questions? Seems too obvious to worry about.

Comment: @Justin it's more for deleted answers since those appear on still-active questions for 10k+ users, whereas deleted questions aren't easily found.  Even though it's obvious the answers in question are deleted because of the coloration, they could be undeleted by the owner and maybe you think it deserves a vote one way or another just in case.

Comment: Sorry, I should have written "deleted posts". My point is just that it only takes one click to pop up the warning, and then you know it's not going to work in the future. Removing the arrows would make it look weird, and it seems like it's not enough of an issue to be worth it (IMHO).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments by @Justin Morgan in that this really isn't very necessary.

The interface has been designed to highlight questions that have been deleted differently as well as including a note that it is deleted. The designers would have hoped that this state for a question would lead people not to think that they could vote on these items. The action is not going to happen very often because it is designed well...and if you do happen to click to vote without realising you get a message saying that the post is deleted and likely you release that it makes perfect sense.

I'm going to have a guess (ignoring laziness as an option here) that it really isn't worth the effort of putting more logic into displaying arrows when the interface has already been designed to reduce this behaviour...and in fact not seeing arrows may well add confusion to an interface that is already very consistent.