# Remove vote buttons on deleted posts

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide voting arrows on deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/hide-voting-arrows-on-deleted-posts)

Some locked posts don't have upvote or downvote buttons since you can't vote on them.

Wouldn't it be a logical step to remove the upvote and downvote buttons from deleted posts as well since you can't vote on them too?

Just a minor improvement in user-experience.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary. I like to see whether or not I've voted on a deleted post. But on the other hand, historically locked posts don't have the buttons either...

Comment: Correction: only **historically locked** questions don't have the voting buttons. Other locks, such as content disputes, do not remove the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

That or somehow show that they are disabled.

Making a user click on something just to show them that they cannot do that is just poor form.