# Disable up/down vote arrows on your own posts

Tags: feature-request, voting, user-interface

I've found similar posts:

1. [Hide the up/down vote arrows on your own posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52595/260198)
2. [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12599/260198)

But people has asked about **hiding** the arrows.

Members can't vote for their own questions, what's the point of having the voting arrows **enabled**?

The system makes you think you can upvote/downvote your own question/answer, but then you get notified that you can't. Why are the up/down vote buttons enabled then?

We can lock arrows on own posts and change the color (to make it obvious that they are inactive). If you are scared that people wouldn't understand why the arrows are inactive, we can add hint on it on hover.

Comment: @DavyM if they see that it's disabled they even will not try to click it.

Comment: Should it solve the problem? No. It's just a suggestion to improve site UX.

Comment: The system makes you think you can upvote/downvote your own question/answer but then you get notified that you can't. Why are the up/down vote buttons enabled then?

Comment: Apparently UX has never been much of a priority at SE.

Answer (score 3):

> Members can't vote for their own questions, what's the point of having the voting arrows enabled?

If the appearance of a one question looks different, some users might subconsciously feel that something is missing.

If users attempt voting on their own question, a message showing

> You can't vote for your own post

will teach it to them instead of leaving some people wondering.

Additionally, also showing the vote buttons on questions asked by oneself provides consistency throughout the layouts of the website.

#### The vote buttons are characteristic for StackExchange.

Comment: The question is not about *hiding* vote buttons, but about *visibly disabling* them. Nothing in this answer addresses this at all.