# Instead of "you can't upvote for yourself message" wouldn't it be better to simply hide the votes images on one's own questions?

Tags: feature-request, design, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts)

Just hide it. Why display it? Keep it enabled, and give the man a false hope he can cheat on the system (wink).

Comment: Often requested, earliest probably being [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts)

Answer (score 3):

The vote buttons are there for a visual consistency. *Every* post (Q or A) on the entire site has the indicators beside them, and it has become rather... iconic. I think it would be visually jarring to occasionally see posts without those icons on them, it would make those posts look unusual.

Ultimately, each user should only run afoul this barrier once or twice, before they come to understand that they will never be able to vote for their own posts. Any change to the buttons would be more damaging to the general site branding than it would be helpful to any people who are consistently trying to upvote themselves.

Although, I always find it frustrating that I can't upvote the post, even though I agree with literally everything in it.

Comment: When a moderator locks a Q & A, the iconic voting icons are hidden. What about those branding issues?