# UI tweak, hide up and down buttons for own posts? Like done for comments

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts)

You are not shown a flag or up button for your own comment. Similarly something can be done for the own posts, answers and questions?