# No need of showing vote button for own posts

Tags: feature-request, voting

We can't vote our own posts in any of the SE sites. Then what is the need of showing the vote buttons to the users for their own posts?

And we display that the user can't vote for their posts everytime he/she clicks the up/downvote(mostly upvote).

[image]

We already hide the vote button for comments where also users can't vote for themselves.

If it's necessary to inform the users that message means we may show it one time and then hide the vote buttons.

It's pleasant to see the score inbetween two triangles, but it' not necessary to show those buttons after a user gets a message that they can't.(it's my point of view)

Comment: Dammit, I keep finding myself wanting to click the dismiss-button on the popup in your screenshot.

Comment: It was [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12599/212576) back in 2009-10

Comment: What's the harm? And if there's no harm, why should the developers spend any time changing it?

Comment: If we hide votes buttons, it will make difficult to judge whether it is [locked post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4720/1369235) or my own post or my own locked post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a good reason for doing this: Consistency.

Quora does this, and it makes it hard to find your answer in a pile of other answers.

My answer (I'm Manish Goregaokar) seems to be a part of the answer above it in the following screenshot:

[image]

If you want a question with fewer answers, see this:

[image]

Basically, we've trained ourselves to identify answers by the voting arrows. Answers without arrows seem to be a part of the previous answer at first glance. Quora's system has always tripped me up when it comes to the voting arrows. Let's not add that here.

Comment: +1, but in SO there is a line between answers and answerer name,image,time and comments(if available) were between answers

Comment: @DIMension10 hmm, it might have gotten improperly cropped while taking the screenshot