# How do I down vote my own questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

I came across a question that was horribly written and lacked any research. Then I noticed I had written it. How would I down vote my own question?

Comment: See also: [Remove vote UI elements beside own question and answer posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12599/21960)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. My question is how do I down vote my own question. His question is how do I down vote my own answer. Your moderation is incorrect.

Comment: It is the exact same principle

Comment: Is a question different than an answer?

Comment: I can downvote this question for you, if you'd like

Answer (score 8):

This is an impossibility - you can not downvote your own question, a better solution would be to edit to improve your question with the appropriate research and written in a clearer manner.

If it is horrendous, then deletion of the question is an option, only if there is no upvoted answer to it.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot vote on your own questions or answers.

If it's really that bad you should probably delete it.