# Visually Differentiate/Highlight comments and answers provided by me for quick reference

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

Whenever I find an interesting answer or comment in a long list of answers, I **Upvote** the answer/comment so that if I land on the same question again in the future, I will know that I have already been to this question and can focus on what I previously found helpful.

But if there's any question where I have given an answer, I cannot upvote my own answer (*which is reasonable*), but this means that my answer won't be visually differentiating unless I look at the author. So I won't know if I have already been to this question earlier in first glance.

Is it just me or does anyone else feel the same?
How does everyone else here get around this?

---

### Summary:

So basically looking for ways to quickly identify 2 things:

My own

- **Answers:** Differentiating an answer without having to scroll to bottom to view the username
- **Comments:** Quickly identifying my comment from a long list - Sometime comments get hidden automatically. But comments

  - from "ActiveUser" should always be visible.
  - upvoted by "ActiveUser" should always be visible

Comment: I think that would be useful for comments. Perhaps the username should be highlighted similar to how the OP's username is highlighted in comments but with a different color/shade.

Comment: I'd just go with disabling (in a visible manner, i.e. different color) or removing the voting arrows for own posts. More simple to implement (probably?) and can't miss that. Sadly, [this exact request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/remove-vote-ui-elements-beside-own-question-and-answer-posts) was declined 12 years ago, but still, might be reconsidered if re-posted these days.

Comment: Highlighting the username may not still be helpful for a long answer because I'll have to scroll to find my name. Highlighting the answer or comments itself will be helpful.

Comment: @Gangula that would be "too much" for many, I assume. Highlight of whole post is done only for deleted posts, or when navigating to a post, for few seconds.

Comment: I agree with you @ShadowWizardIsVaccinatedV3. What I would really like is to identify it at the top of the answer - without the need to scroll. And your comment for disabling arrows could be helpful, if they're made visibly obvious that they are disabled.

Comment: @Gangula I was only talking about comments. Highlighting the username on comments would be consistent with the current way of highlighting the OP's username and would be pretty hard to miss. As to answers, I agree that a different way is probably better but I did not comment on that because I don't find it useful for me personally. I don't have anything against it though.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. But just curious, even for comments, are the OP's comments made always visible? I mean when there are too many comments, SO often hides some of them. So is there a chance that the OP's comments get hidden too?

Comment: @Gangula Yes, the OP's comments are not treated specially when deciding which comments to hide. That's only decided based on votes (AFAICT).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a browser extension called "Stack Me First" which does this - currently available in [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-me-first/pmjhehdfjfahnlgdblnhhfcimegodmnj), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stack-me-first/) & [Microsoft Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/stack-me-first/andilefigneejkadafmdfcmjdnabfbhi).

You can check out a demo of what this plugin does in the following [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/X6_RQKMUnNI).

---

"Stack Me First" is a browser Extension (currently available in Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge & Firefox) that highlights & lists:

- Answers posted by the current user in the currently visible page of the Stack Overflow.
- Comments posted by the current user in the currently visible page of the Stack Overflow

Optionally, you can also use the login button in the popup to highlight & list:

- Answers hidden due to pagination of multiple answers
- Comments hidden under "show more comments"
- Linked questions that have been Upvoted/Bookmarked/Posted by the logged in user.

check out the ReadMe.md at the following page for instructions on how to use:
https://github.com/AnweshGangula/StackMeFirst#readme

[image: Screenshot of "Stack Me First" Browser Extension Popup]